# Java Swing Application not running in 64bit

Tags: java, swing, 64-bit

I have one really weird problem.

I have one Swing Application which we recently upgraded, that does not run at all in a Java 1.7/1.8 64bit enviroment.

More specifically, the application works perfectly in 32bit Java installations of 1.7.0_52+, but if you place it in a 64bit enviroment it does not open at all.

Running it from the console with the -verbose, the last message before it stops loading is:

```
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAutoShutDown$1 from c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\lib\rt.jar]
```

There is no message in any log above that suggests an error has occured, and no exception or other message thrown. The application's java enviroment remains in memory with a cpu usage of ~40%.

What makes this wierd is that the same application runs from the same PC if I launch it via eclipse. There is only one java installation on my PC, and both the application and Eclipse use this same JDK.

I am unable to think of anything that could cause a problem, and I am at a loss. Does anyone have anyidea?

Comment: I suggest that you launch the application under debugger control, so that you can attach a remote debugger to see where it actually hangs. (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/975342/1611055). Another alternative is to dump a stack trace (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2124708/1611055) which might get you some insight to where the application hangs

Comment: Thank you, I will be trying this immediately

Answer (score -1):

The 64-bit JVM using 32-bit references can address 32+3 bits of address space as it can assume the lowest 3 bits of an objects address is 0.

Most 32-bit JVMs are limited to around 1.2-1.5 GB.

Comment: Besides that it does not answer the question - do you have any official reference to that theory?

Comment: yes  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178598/32-bit-or-64-bit-application-on-64-bit-os

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407699/64-bit-java-for-small-stand-alone-applications

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178598/32-bit-or-64-bit-application-on-64-bit-os

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely interesting reading - still, it does not answer the question, since the issue it is not about a larger memory footprint with the 64 bit JVM, but about the application hanging completely ...