# Java 10 (and following) on 32-Bit systems

Tags: java, x86, java-10

As far as I know there are no plans from oracle to ship java for 32 Bit - but maybe I misunderstand the situation.
If I'm correct - what do we all do if we need to support 32-Bit libraries (dlls)? And whats about 32 Bit OSes out there?
Currently this seems to be a huge impact in the future but as I said - maybe I'm wrong.
Fact is that we can't download a Java 10 runtime in 32 Bit as there are only 64 Bit Download-Links.

Comment: 32-bit x86 is obsolete.  Don't plan on everything supporting it indefinitely.  (I don't know any specific details about Java 10, though, sorry.)  Binary-only software is a lot less future-proof than source code.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. Then we need to get rid of 32-bit 3rd party libraries which sounds easier than it is because there are legacy libraries out there...

Answer (score 6):

Had a similar issue, just with Java 11. Eventually, I found a 32bit JDK and JRE for Java 11 on https://adoptopenjdk.net/ (for the Hotspot JVM). With the 32bit JDK, I successfully connected to a 32bit dll. I hope this is useful for others who face a similar situation.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle is not the only party building and distributing OpenJDK.
For example Azul maintains, but does not certify as TCK-compliant, 32bit windows builds as part of their [Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/) project.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 32-bit Java 10 distribution from Oracle. And there will be no Java 11 distribution as well. There are a few companies which offer a 32-bit support though (like Azul). However, I recommend continuing using Java 8 32-bit. It has official support from Oracle and it will be maintained until January 2019.

Comment: I would have tentatively agreed with you when you posted that comment, but of course, it's past that time now, and there are new issues that are addressed by later versions of Java that aren't addressed by Java 8, such as better support for ultra-hi-res (e.g. 4K) displays. The resources at the link posted below by jechterhoff appear to be a better way forward.

Answer (score 1):

For RHEL, redhat still offers 32bit java-11 in their repository:

```
java-11-openjdk-devel.i686       1:11.0.6.10-1.el7_7
```