# jdk8 windows 10 for android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem I hope to find it solved, Windows installed on my computer is Windows 10 - 32 bit Can I install Android Studio on it? But the jdk version 8 was not compatible with Windows 10, they want the latest version and there is no higher than this in the 32 bit while 64 bit is up to version 12, is there a solution to my problem? Or should I change Windows to 64 bit?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976684/java-10-and-following-on-32-bit-systems

Comment: AFAIR Android Studio come with built-in JRE/JDK. You don't need an additional JRE/JDK installed. You can see it on the Android Studio web page in the "System requirements" section: regarding software the requirement is only "Microsoft® Windows® 7/8/10" - no Java mentioned.

Comment: even if you manage to install JDK-10, android studio won't work efficiently on 4Gb RAM limit especially if you run an emulator; I encourage you to upgrade your system if it's possible for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using 64 bit in this day and age.

JDK 8 is comaptible with Windows 10, just maybe not the 32 bit version.

Hence, upgrading to 64 bit is the best option.

Comment: Which bit architecture you use isn't controllable - it depends on the architecture of your hardware and OS. There is "backward compatibility" - 32 bit can run on 64 bit, but 64 bit [cannot run on 32 bit](https://www.quora.com/Can-a-64-bit-computer-run-32-bit-software) without emulation. Installing 64 it is in this case incorrect. OP uses a 32 bit Windows, which cannot run 64 bit Java. Upgrading the OS can be an option, but it's also only possible if the underlying architecture supports it

Comment: But I ran it on my computer I changed Windows for PC and now I'm working on 64bit, how do I know that my hardware does not support 64-bit Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official link for Java 8 32-bit

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Search for Windows x86 in this page
and click on the link jdk-8u202-windows-i586.exe

Be sure to accept the license first before downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenJDK from AdoptOpenJDK. You will find 32-bit version for windows.

Here is the link:
https://adoptopenjdk.net/